# Parse Array in nested JSON with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to write a `FromJSON` function for Aeson.

The JSON:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "movies": [
    {
      "id": "771315522",
      "title": "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone (Wizard's Collection)",
      "posters": {
        "thumbnail": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_mob.jpg",
        "profile": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_pro.jpg",
        "detailed": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_det.jpg",
        "original": "http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_ori.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The ADT: `data Movie = Movie {id::String, title::String}`

My attempt:

```
instance FromJSON Movie where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
       movies <- parseJSON =<< (o .: "movies") :: Parser Array
       v <- head $ decode movies
       return $ Movie <$>
           (v .: "movies" >>= (.: "id") ) <*>
           (v .: "movies" >>= (.: "title") )
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

This gives `Couldn't match expected type 'Parser t0' with actual type 'Maybe a0' In the first argument of 'head'`.

As you can see, I'm trying to pick the first of the movies in the `Array`, but I wouldn't mind getting a list of Movies either (in case there are several in the Array).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to parse a single `Movie` from a JSON array of movies, you can do something like this:

```
instance FromJSON Movie where
    parseJSON (Object o) = do
        movieValue <- head <$> o .: "movies"
        Movie <$> movieValue .: "id" <*> movieValue .: "title"
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

But the safer route would be to parse a `[Movie]` via `newtype` wrapper:

```
main = print $ movieList <$> decode "{\"total\":1,\"movies\":[ {\"id\":\"771315522\",\"title\":\"Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone (Wizard's Collection)\",\"posters\":{\"thumbnail\":\"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_mob.jpg\",\"profile\":\"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_pro.jpg\",\"detailed\":\"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_det.jpg\",\"original\":\"http://content7.flixster.com/movie/11/16/66/11166609_ori.jpg\"}}]}"

newtype MovieList = MovieList {movieList :: [Movie]}

instance FromJSON MovieList where
    parseJSON (Object o) = MovieList <$> o .: "movies"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

data Movie = Movie {id :: String, title :: String}

instance FromJSON Movie where
    parseJSON (Object o) = Movie <$> o .: "id" <*> o .: "title"
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Answer (score 8):

It's usually easiest to match the structure of your ADTs and instances to the structure of your JSON.

Here, I've added a newtype `MovieList` to deal with the outermost object so that the instance for `Movie` only has to deal with a single movie. This also gives you multiple movies for free via the `FromJSON` instance for lists.

```
data Movie = Movie { id :: String, title :: String }

newtype MovieList = MovieList [Movie]

instance FromJSON MovieList where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    MovieList <$> (o .: "movies")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

instance FromJSON Movie where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Movie <$> (o .: "id")
          <*> (o .: "title")
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't think of introducing another type. May I ask a quick follow up? If I'd like to extend the `Movie` type to include some more fields like `filePath` or `myRating`, would you recommend adding a new type `myMovie`, or introducing a few `Maybe` fields to the `Movie` type and fill them up after the `decode`? (I guess filling up would actually mean making a new instance with all fields, since ADT are immutable..)

Comment: @mb21: Either approach will work fine. It depends on the rest of your application. If those fields are always added immediately after decoding, it might make sense to make a new type so that the rest of your functions don't have to deal with a `Maybe` that should always be `Just`. On the other hand, if those fields are optional it makes sense to keep them in a `Maybe`.